# query fails in php didn't know the reason

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert faculty details into database table named faculty 
I stored $_POST values  after ensuring that $_POST value is not empty.

```
$$sql ="INSERT INTO faculty (fac_id,name, f_name, gender, cc, designation, department, email, contact) VALUES('$f_id', '$name', '$father_name', '$gender','$cc', '$designation',  '$department', '$email', '$contact')";

if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
{
    render("success.php");  
}
else echo "error";
```

when this executes it always returns prints error.
please help.[faculty table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEeic.png)

Comment: Maybe a typo `$$sql`...or you can do an `echo $sql;` and check if the result is correct...

Comment: You should also use a prepared statement, you could be sql-injecting yourself as well...

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Add these lines to the beginning of that PHP file. It will give you the error details. **error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);**

Comment: Type "echo" before your query and excute that query into your database, is it gives some error to you?

Comment: When I copy the sql in php myadmin it gives error for contact out of range then just i change int to char for contact column. Thank you very much  guys

Answer (score 0):

Check your table for any not null field

also

There is no native PHP function called "render()", it's part of Drupal, and it's probably explained in their documentation.

Comment: actually its user defined function.